# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. (I NEED HELP!!!)

Tags: javascript, html, json, syntax

I am creating a chat website and I am not very educated on what I am doing as I am 14 years old. But I want help from experts or people of higher education than me and help guide me on what I did wrong.

This is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Chat App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Person selector: this contains buttons for user to select whether to chat as John or Jane -->
    <div class="person-selector">
      <button class="button person-selector-button active-person" id="john-selector">John</button>
      <button class="button person-selector-button" id="jane-selector">Jane</button>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-container">
      <h2 class="chat-header">John chatting...</h2>

      <div class="chat-messages">
        <div class="message blue-bg">
          <div class="message-sender">John</div>
          <div class="message-text">Hey Jane, what's up?</div>
          <div class="message-timestamp">10:30 AM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="message gray-bg">
          <div class="message-sender">Jane</div>
          <div class="message-text">Not much, just living the dream. How about you?</div>
          <div class="message-timestamp">10:35 AM</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <form class="chat-input-form">
        <input type="text" class="chat-input" required placeholder="Type here, John..." />
        <button type="submit" class="button send-button">Send</button>
      </form>
      <button class="button clear-chat-button">Clear Chat</button>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*This is the json code*

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the syntax error crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. and I have no idea what to do.

I looked through the forums to see what was wrong and I couldn't find anything straight forward. If anyone has discord or something that would be great if you want to help guide me, or you can just simply respond with the answer to this problem. Thanks in advance, this forum is great!